# Error: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'

Tags: wcf, authentication, wshttpbinding

I keep getting the above error when my client program tries to call my WCF service method. It is passing credentials via ClientCredential.UserName.

I am not able to figure out what's happening here and all the posts related to this kind of issue are not solving this problem.

Mine is a shared hosting Environment on Godaddy server where my WCF service is hosted.

Configuration is as follows:

```
<endpoint 
    name="wsBinding" 
    address="" 
    binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    contract="ServiceLib.IBooking" 
    bindingConfiguration="myWSSettings"/>


<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myWSSettings">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: You specified "transport" security and then configured a "message" security clientCredentialType.  Is your intent to use transport security or message security?

Comment: Hi Rick, my intent is to use SSL for secured channel and use username/password kind of way to authenticate user.